# How to configure Logstash filter for multiline conditional check of a dataset

Tags: elk

I need to display a graph on Kibana where I need to process the below logs. Below lines are logged when an email is sent to a customer. I have to write logstash filter to interpret the below logs as
1. To whom are emails being sent.
2. What is the reference number for the requested email? (here REF is REF/2019.45815)
3. "Return code" from the below logs (A zero return code is for successful mail sent, any other digit except zero means that the mail is not sent successfully)

As this is a multiline log, I am having difficulty in creating relations of one keyword with another. Is it possible and how? Any leads would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

2019-10-02 13:07:46.004 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EMailListTo:ATSNetworking@aggreko.biz
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EMailListTo: raj.bassan@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EMailListTo: cairo.csp@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EMailListTo: harsh.bhardwaj@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc:r.sarthy@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc: rahulk.sharma@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc: chris.hobbs@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc: david.dupre@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc: raj.bassan@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc: devanshu.kumar@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - EmailListCc: leandro.reis@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - the finalEmailString which should be the TO list is  : ATSNetworking@aggreko.biz, raj.bassan@orange.com, cairo.csp@orange.com, harsh.bhardwaj@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - the ccfinalEmailString which should be the CC list is  : r.sarthy@orange.com, rahulk.sharma@orange.com, chris.hobbs@orange.com, david.dupre@orange.com, raj.bassan@orange.com, devanshu.kumar@orange.com, leandro.reis@orange.com
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  -  FileName - content.html FileList - output_attachments/planned_notification_{18073}.html DocIncluded - INCLU
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  -  FileName - ORANGE_OBS_LOGO.png FileList - output_attachments/ORANGE_OBS_LOGO.png DocIncluded - JOIN
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  -  FileName - carrier_notification.ics FileList - output_attachments/carrier_notification_{18073}.ics DocIncluded - JOIN
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  -  FileName - Carrier_maintenance_data_G_02_Oct_2019_18073_AGGREKO_PLC.xlsx FileList - output_attachments/maintanance_data_file_cmt_{18073}.xlsx DocIncluded - JOIN
2019-10-02 13:07:46.005 DEBUG main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - Sending mail to recipiants by flowtool starts (for normal scanario) for subject -Orange Business Services Carrier Planned Maintenance for AGGREKO PLC
2019-10-02 13:07:47.576 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - Return Code from flow :0
2019-10-02 13:07:47.576 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - -----Operation completed 
2019-10-02 13:07:47.576 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - Mail Successfuly sent!!!!
2019-10-02 13:07:47.576 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - Email sent to recipiants successfully, status : true
2019-10-02 13:07:47.604 INFO  main       [plannedLogger                           ]  - Successfully update MAIL_STATUS for Maintenances : [52320134:REF/2019.45815:LOGGED:CSM] value of result is : 1

Comment: It is really appreciated if you can post what you have tried so far and specifically where you have stuck. I can help you with logstash filtering

Comment: I can't find any solution to this issue. Actually, I am stuck at this logic :
As I have to treat the above log as one dataset, any filter that I apply in the logstash will treat each line according to the filtered conditions and will give multiple matching values where i just want one for a single dataset

Comment: please share your logstash filter

Comment: I have no filter, don't know where to start. Can you please suggest a logic so that I can build on that.